# Drawer navigator in react-native using react-navigation 4.x

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I want to create a drawer navigator using react navigation 4.x in react native, but not getting drawer menu in left side of the screen. Here is my code for the navigation component.
It includes three screens First,Home and Login that i want to show in drawer menu.

```
import {
  createSwitchNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
  //createDrawerNavigator,
  // createBottomTabNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';

import FirstScreen from '../screen/FirstScreen';
import HomeScreen from '../screen/HomeScreen';
import LoginScreen from '../screen/LoginScreen';

const AppStack = createStackNavigator ({
  First: {screen: FirstScreen},
  // Dashboard: {screen: AppDrawerNavigator},
  Login: {screen: LoginScreen},
  Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
})
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Dashboard: {screen:AppStack}
});

const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  First: {screen: FirstScreen},
  Dashboard: {screen: AppDrawerNavigator},
  Login: {screen: LoginScreen},
  Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
});

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(switchNavigator);

export default AppNavigator;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep your `AppStack` as stackNavigator then you have to create custom drawer navigator and need to pass it on `createDrawerNavigator`.

So first create **CustomDrawer.js** as below :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

class CustomDrawer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      menus: [
        key: 'First', title: 'First', screen: 'FirstScreen',
        key: 'Login', title: 'Login', screen: 'LoginScreen',
        key: 'Home', title: 'Home', screen: 'HomeScreen'
      ]
    };
  }

  navigateToScreen = (route) => {
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: route
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
    this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
        {
          this.state.menus.map((menu) => (
            <TouchableOpacity key={menu.key} onPress={() => this.navigateToScreen(menu.screen)}>
              <Text>{menu.title}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))
        }
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomDrawer;
```

Then on in your **AppNavigator.js** pass `CustomDrawer` as `contentComponent` in `createDrawerNavigator` as below :

```js
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Dashboard: {
    screen: AppStack,
  }
}, {
  contentComponent: CustomDrawer, // Pass here
  // others props
  drawerBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,.9)',
  overlayColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#fff',
    activeBackgroundColor: '#6b52ae',
  },
});
```

If you want more style you can done in **CustomDrawer.js**.

Comment: getting error in CustomDrawer.js, on line 12 as the type cast expression to be wrpaped in paranthesis. Thanks but i need some simple example as i am new to react navigation 4.x. No issue only i need to understand simple how drawer we can create.

Answer (score 0):

you are returning the switch navigator, try this way , embed switch-navigator object with drawer-navigator object and return drawer-navigator object. refer below,

```
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  First: {screen: FirstScreen},
  Login: {screen: LoginScreen},
  Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
  switchNavigator: switchNavigator
});
const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(AppDrawerNavigator);
export default AppNavigator;
```

Comment: export AppDrawerNavigator instead of switch navigator

Comment: I have edited the code try like this and let me know

Comment: working thanks. But mainly issue was i hadn't configured gesturehandler and other dependency hence it was not showing drawer after swipe. Now configured dependencies properly. Link:https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html

Comment: oh key. have a nice day. please do a up vote if it helped . thanks